# Amazon MWS SubmitFeed: Incorrect Signature

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-mws

Ive been working on this for a few days now and Im kind of lost at this point and was hoping for a little help to get over this speed bump.  Im pretty new to programming and python but Ive created a few requests for Amazons Product api and figured that the SubmitFeed Cant be that different.  Ive ran the same setup in the MWS scratch pad and get a different signature then what my code creates. Im not sure what Im doing wrong, Ive went over the payload several times and nothing has stood out. Any help would be great.

```
def get_data():
    global SECRET_KEY

    request_description = '&'.join(['%s=%s' % (k, urllib.parse.quote(payload[k], safe='-_.~')) for k in sorted(payload)])
    #print(request_description)

    sig_data = method + "\n" + domain.replace('https://', '').lower() + "\n" + URI + "\n" + request_description

    sig_data = bytes(sig_data, 'utf-8')
    SECRET_KEY1 = bytes(SECRET_KEY, 'utf-8')
    sig_data = hmac.new(SECRET_KEY1, sig_data, digestmod=hashlib.sha256)
    print(sig_data.hexdigest())
    calc_signature = urllib.parse.quote(base64.b64encode(sig_data.digest()), safe='-_.~')

    sig = calc_signature
    print(sig)
    url = '%s%s?%s&Signature=%s' % (domain, URI, request_description, sig)

    r = requests.post(url)

    file = open('C:\Python34\Python34\CompetitorsPrices.xml', 'w+')
    print(r.text, end="", file=file)
    file.close()



SECRET_KEY = '**'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = '**'
SELLER_ID = '**'
MARKETPLACE_ID = '**'

Action = 'SubmitFeed'
SignatureMethod = 'HmacSHA256'
SignatureVersion = '2'
Timestamp = '2017-02-17T18:51:08Z'
Version = '2009-01-01'
URI = '/'
domain = 'https://mws.amazonservices.com'
method = 'POST'

payload = {'AWSAccessKeyId': AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
           'Action': Action,
           'Merchant': SELLER_ID,
           'SignatureVersion': SignatureVersion,
           'Timestamp': Timestamp,
           'Version': Version,
           'SignatureMethod': SignatureMethod,
           'MarketplaceIdList.Id.1': MARKETPLACE_ID,
           'FeedType': '_POST_FLAT_FILE_PRICEANDQUANTITYONLY_UPDATE_DATA_',
           'PurgeAndReplace': 'false'}

get_data()


print('Press Enter to Exit')
```